# Implementation can't be assignable from Interface?

Tags: java, spring, interface

Assume I have:

```
public interface A {

    BigDecimal getAmountValue();

    void setAmountValue(BigDecimal amountValue);

    String getCurrency();

    void setCurrency(String currency);    
}
```

and

```
public class B implements A {

    protected BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    protected String currency;

    public B() {
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal getAmountValue() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAmountValue(BigDecimal amountValue) {
        amount = amountValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }    
}
```

I want to know why `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isAssignable(B, A) return false`.

In my application, I'm using a dozer copy with `BeanUtils.copyProperties()`, and i was able to do it since I tried to upgrade spring version to 3.2.9

Now, `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` added `ClassUtils.isAssignable()` and now my application is not working correctly.

I don't really know why it's returning false, and i would like to understand it before I think about a workaround...

Thanks for any help! And sorry if my English is not correct, I'm not native.

Comment: You need to call `org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isAssignable(A, B)`. It is allowed to do `A = new B()` but not allowed `B = new A()`

Comment: `A` is indeed not assignable to `B`. If Spring does that, then it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

from doc :

> `isAssignable(java.lang.Class<?> lhsType, java.lang.Class<?> rhsType)` : Check if the right-hand side type may be assigned to the left-hand
>   side type

Keep that on mind ,

check this basic  example `ClassUtils.isAssignable(Object.class, String.class) = true`

that make sense because **Every String is an object**

but `ClassUtils.isAssignable( String.class,Object.class) = false`

because Object is not necessary a string type